# How to make jQuery recognize radiobutton change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio buttons, first makes the text red, the other makes it yellow. but i cant make it blue. please help thanks.

**Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/h6ye7/17/**

```
<form>
    Option 1<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio1" value="Option 1" />
    Option 2<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio1" value="Option 2" />
</form>

<div class="text">sad dsffsadf sdsdf sfadfsd</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        if($('.radio1').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('.text').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        else
        {
            $('.text').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: bcoz yellow is not blue

Comment: there are four answers..each one correct..no one here is hungry for reputation.Accept the answer you feel is correct.

Comment: They are all correct, however, they are solved it the long way when it can be solved with a small change.

Comment: @OPUS:- Nice one!!! +1

Comment: I wrote the top answer myself, since no-one was willing to do it.

Comment: @JanAnderssen:- If you dont want to accept any answer. Then just post your solution in answer and accept that. Simple!!! :)

Comment: @JanAnderssen:ohh..you are too smart my friend

Comment: @JanAnderssen You do not need to post the solution in your question. Everyone can see the post you marked as answer below.

Comment: @ComFreek nah, it's better maybe other people benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.radio1` selects both radio inputs!

There are several options:

- Assign an ID
- Use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

  ```
  if ($(".radio1").eq(0).is(':checked'))
  ```

  [→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ye7/14/)
- Use `:first`

  ```
  if ($(".radio1:first").is(':checked'))
  ```

  [→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ye7/15/)
- If you really want to, you can also assign different classes (I do **not** recommend this method for the simple reason that IDs are meant to be used in this case instead of classes!)

  HTML:

  ```
  Option 1<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio1" value="Option 1" />
  Option 2<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio2" value="Option 2" />
  ```

  JS (the same as you had at the beginning):

  ```
  if ($(".radio1").is(':checked'))
  ```

  → [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ye7/17/)

Comment: answer5: assign #radio1 #radio2 :)

Comment: @ComFreek oh yeah, didn't see that because you didn't have any codes below it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:first` to do this:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    if($('.radio1:first').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('.text').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.text').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ye7/9/)

Answer (score 0):

I gave a different class to second radio button `.radio2` and that solved it.

**http://jsfiddle.net/h6ye7/17/**

```
<form>
    Option 1<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio1" value="Option 1" />
    Option 2<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio2" value="Option 2" />
</form>
```

Comment: I would rather use IDs in this case. Classes are meant to group elements. If you want to identify exactly one element, you should use an ID. (They both work, of course.)

Comment: I added your point in my answer -  including a warning! @Rahul is right, it's not (always) about reputation here!